# Excel Custom function returns #BUSY

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel, scriptlab

I am using Script Lab for defining custom function in Excel. Even the most trivial function returns #BUSY result.

This is test funcition that returns #BUSY error.

```
/** @CustomFunction */
function add10(x: number): number {
 return x + 10;
}
```

I am using office 365 personal subscription if it makes any sence.
Working on Windows 11 Pro x64

Comment: Are you working on Windows, on Mac, or on the Web? Also, please go through the custom functions quickstart at https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-custom-functions-quickstart on the same machine using the same subscription. Do you get the same symptoms?

Comment: Windows 11 Pro x64

Comment: Custom Functions Quickstart works fine and registers predefined functions. They don't return #Busy error code

Comment: In that case, it might be a bug in Script Lab. I recommend that you give the Stack community a couple of days to solve it. If you don't get a useful answer by then, you can create a bug in the [Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/issues/new/choose) repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, which I managed to fix when I upgraded my local node.js from v18.6.0 to v18.17.1.